# how to center tile layer in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to center a tile layer in OpenLayers 3 but it seems to ignore the center attribute of the map. I know the height and width of the original big image if it helps.

here is my code (also available in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wedenoyupi/edit?html,js,output)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <title>XYZ</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id="map" class="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
 <script>
   var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://thinker.cloudapp.net/test/{z}-{x}-{y}.png',
    wrapX: false
  })
   });

   var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 2
  })
   });
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I center the map, and if possible zoom to fit screen width or height?

**Update:**

I've updated the code and added a jsbin link too.
The original image size is 4864x3328 if it helps.

I think this has to do with projection and setting the grid size in pixels, but i couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what you need. Center what? The map DOM element? Or a specific map coordinate?

Comment: The map is actually a huge picture cropped to tiles. I want to see the entire image after initialization as big as it can be to fit the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer isn't a good one. Go this way:

```
var pixelProj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'pixel',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: [0, 0, 4864, 3328]
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: pixelProj,
    wrapX: false,
    url: 'http://thinker.cloudapp.net/test/{z}-{x}-{y}.png'
  })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  view: new ol.View({
    zoom: 2,
    center: [1364, 2400],
    projection: pixelProj
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/6f233kLy/

<strike>To achieve this you'll need to wait until all tiles are loaded, then get the [layer extent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html#getExtent), finally [fit the view](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit) to this extent.</strike>

```
var tile_loading = 0, tile_loaded = 0;
yourTileLayer.getSource().on('tileloadstart', function(evt){
  ++tile_loading;
});
yourTileLayer.getSource().on('tileloadend', function(evt){
  ++tile_loaded;
  if(tile_loaded === tile_loading){
    tile_loading = 0;
    tile_loaded = 0;

    // put some logic here to do just once
    // all tiles are loaded - get the layer extent
    var extent = yourTileLayer.getExtent();
    map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but if i use your code the line "yourTileLayer.getExtent()" return an undefined

Comment: `yourTileLayer` has to be changed to your `layer` variable name.

Comment: obviously that's what i was doing. It seems that because I'm using tile layer the extent is undefined. Any idea how can I set the extent if i know the pixel height and width of the image (before it was tiled) ?

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how did you calculate the center numbers (1364, 2400) ?

Comment: It's `width / 2` and `height / 2`.

Comment: no it's not since `width = 4864` and `width/2 = 2432`, and `height = 3328` and `height/2 = 1664` - different numbers from yours

Comment: I'm sorry if i annoyed you, i simply wanted to understand exactly your answer. Anyway the pixelProjection pointed me to the right direction and for that you should have the bounty, enjoy :)